# JSON to CSV for certain keys

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, csv

I have a gigantic json file that I need to convert only some of the object keys into a csv. Here is a sample of what the json looks like:

[image]

Here is also some formatted raw sample data and not just a screenshot:

```
    {
  "1234567890": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  },
  "2345678912": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  },
  "3456789012": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction of the best way to create a csv that creates 4 columns with the highlighted values highlighted in the screenshot above? So the output I would be looking for would be this:

[image]

Can I do this with Node.js? Maybe some other library that does exactly this? A job for python? I prefer some kind of Javascript solution but am open to any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It seems fairly simple to script yourself. iterate over all record keys, then all cards within a key, and for every record-card combo, output a line of text that includes the things you care about.

Comment: You say it's gigantic. Will it fit into RAM all at once?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```py
source = {
  "1234567890": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  },
  "2345678912": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  },
  "3456789012": {
    "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
    "cards": {
      "252632123": {
        "id": "id_554874455544456646",
        "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
        "last4": "5555",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2024,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  }
}

for key in source:
   record = []
   record.append(key)
   record_id = list(source[key]['cards'].keys())[0]
   record.append(record_id)
   exp_m = source[key]['cards'][record_id]['exp_month']
   exp_y = source[key]['cards'][record_id]['exp_year']
   record.append(exp_m)
   record.append(exp_y)
   print(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSV package on NPM, or emit the CSV yourself. In both cases, you'll have to iterate over your array to decide what to emit (either by storing it in an array to pass to the module, or directly emit a line to the output file). Iterating over your data would look like this:

```js
const data = {
    "1234567890": {
        "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
        "cards": {
            "252632123": {
                "id": "id_554874455544456646",
                "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
                "last4": "5555",
                "exp_month": 12,
                "exp_year": 2024,
                "brand": "Visa"
            }
        }
    },
    "2345678912": {
        "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
        "cards": {
            "252632123": {
                "id": "id_554874455544456646",
                "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
                "last4": "5555",
                "exp_month": 12,
                "exp_year": 2024,
                "brand": "Visa"
            }
        }
    },
    "3456789012": {
        "id": "sdggdfgfhfgdhfg",
        "cards": {
            "252632123": {
                "id": "id_554874455544456646",
                "fingerprint": "fsadljfhnsdikiubcb",
                "last4": "5555",
                "exp_month": 12,
                "exp_year": 2024,
                "brand": "Visa"
            }
        }
    }
};

for (const record_id in data) {
    const { cards } = data[record_id];
    for (const card_id in cards) {
        const { exp_month, exp_year } = cards[card_id];
        console.log({ record_id, card_id, exp_month, exp_year });
    }
}
```

This spits out a single row for every card, including the `record_id` it's part of. At that point, format as CSV and write to file or pass it to a module that formats it as CSV for you.